# Send data between Android and Arduino via Wifi

Tags: android, error-handling, arduino, wifi

I program my Arduino and when in my tablet type 192.168.4.1 arduino send me Html page but when I use this code I cant receive any data and I get this error:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 192.168.4.1

How can I solve this problem?

```
private void getdata(){

    try {
        URL url = new URL("192.168.4.1");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String data = "", line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // data += line + "\n";
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } //end try

    Log.e("errrorrrrrrrrrrrr", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `http://` to your url :

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1");
```

Comment: do you use any port ? try to add `/` at the end

Comment: now I test these
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1:80");
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/");
but didnt work

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: you need to add the `http` or `https` so it knows which protocol you are using

Comment: Dear I test these
URL url = new URL("ht tp://192.168.4.1:80");

URL url = new URL("ht t p ://192.168.4.1/");

It s base on http with 80 port....I cant use https

Comment: stackoverflow. filters http in my answer

Comment: i had your same problem and i fix it like that, sorry no more ideas

Comment: I do that thanks dear


I use Thread and use  URL url = new URL("ht tp://192.168.4.1:80")

Comment: @m-tech Why did you accept this answer, if it didn't solve your problem?